# Java - a method for not repeat the NIF

Tags: java

I have this method

```
public static boolean DNIRepetido(String dni1){
        boolean aux=false;

        for (Cliente cliente : cli) {
            if(dni1==cliente.dni){
                aux=true;
            }else{
                aux=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return aux;
    }
```

but when I implement it, it doesen't works fine

```
do{
    System.out.print("DNI: ");
    c.dni=sc.next();
}while((ValidarDNI(c.dni)==false)&&(DNIRepetido(c.dni)==false));
```

("ValidarDNI" works fine)

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOO.. `==` again :_(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare strings via the `equals()` method.

```
if(dni1==cliente.dni){
```

should be

```
if(dni1.equals(cliente.dni)){
```

(you may wish to cater for null references in the above)

The == operator is using *reference* equality, whereas the `equals()` method compares the actual objects (i.e. is the array of characters the same - are they the same string).

Note that `==` will work if you're using [interned](http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/) strings, which directly instantiated strings are.

Comment: My dream is that a day will pass without any question about `==` vs `equals()`.

Comment: I second that completely

Answer (score 2):

Strings have to be compared for equality (same content) with equals method. It's a [frequent mistake](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html).

Also, I would check the `DNIRepetido` exit condition. I guess you want to exit when you find a repeated DNI. In your case if you find a repeated DNI (and thus set `aux = true`) the next iteration of the for loop would change that fact:

```
public static boolean DNIRepetido(String dni1){
        for (Cliente cliente : cli) {
            if(dni1.equals(cliente.dni)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The context isn't clear but

```
if (dni1==cliente.dni) { // is the wrong way to compare two strings
```

and you should `break` on a match; not when it doesn't

```
if(dni1==cliente.dni){
  aux=true;
  break; // here
} else {
  aux=false;
  // break; // not here
}
```

Use `equals()` instead *(almost always to compare Objects)*

```
if (dni1 != null && dni1.equals(cliente.getDni())) {
// this compares the actual text content; not the reference
```

And, I suggest you make your member fields private and *use getter methods* to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another problem in your code, besides the equals() method for comparing Strings.

When you enter the loop, the first time you'll find a client with a different DNI, you'll quit the loop and won't check for other client DNIs. You should avoid the else part of your code:

```
public static boolean DNIRepetido(String dni1){
        boolean aux=false;

        for (Cliente cliente : cli) {
            if(dni1.equals(cliente.dni)){
                aux=true;
            }
        }
        return aux;
    }
```